# Import excel (xlsx) into mysql database with php

Tags: php, mysql

i had trouble to upload my excel file and import the data into the database. I was alway getting the error code :

> Notice: Undefined index: file in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\Shamcey\importProspect.php on line 27
>
> Notice: Undefined index: file in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\Shamcey\importProspect.php on line 28 Invalid
>   File:Please Upload CSV File

I had try many way to rename the file tag in the code but also failed to do so. I try research on google for the solution but non of the solution work. Please help me. I know that PHPExcel will be highly recommend to use but i don't really know how to start with the PHPExcel as i still new to php.

Here is my php code:

```
  function doprospects(){

    if(isset($_POST["Import"]))
    {
        //First we need to make a connection with the database
        $host='localhost'; // Host Name.
        $db_user= 'root'; //User Name
        $db_password= '';
        $db= 'csci311'; // Database Name.
        $conn=mysql_connect($host,$db_user,$db_password) or die (mysql_error());
        mysql_select_db($db) or die (mysql_error());
        echo $filename=$_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
        if($_FILES["file"]["size"] > 0)
        {
            $file = fopen($filename, "r");
            //$sql_data = "SELECT * FROM prod_list_1 ";
            while (($emapData = fgetcsv($file, 10000, ",")) !== FALSE)
            {
                //print_r($emapData);
                //exit();
                $sql = "INSERT into prospects(sno,name,position,positiontype,organization,industry,address,teloff,telfax,telhp,email,consultant,qualification,certification,member,membertype,remarks,state,sourceofclient) values ('$emapData[0]','$emapData[1]',,'$emapData[2]',,'$emapData[3]',,'$emapData[4]',,'$emapData[5]',,'$emapData[6]',,'$emapData[7]',,'$emapData[8]',,'$emapData[9]',,'$emapData[10]',,'$emapData[11]',,'$emapData[12]',,'$emapData[13]',,'$emapData[14]',,'$emapData[15]',,'$emapData[16]',,'$emapData[17]','$emapData[18]')";
                mysql_query($sql);
            }
            fclose($file);
            echo 'CSV File has been successfully Imported';
            header('Location: index.php');
        }
        else
            echo 'Invalid File:Please Upload CSV File';
    }
```

Here is how my excel file look like

[image: Prospect.xlsx]

Is there possible to only enter the data only withouth insert the header into the database?

Comment: your reading an excel file as if it was a csv file, its not

Comment: @Dagon Is there any possible to use excel file to import into database? I had try to save it as csv file but it also can't be upload. Any solution?

Comment: You'll need to save the Excel file as a CSV file.  You can do this by doing a "Save As" in Excel and set the "Save as type" to `CSV (Comma delimited)`.

Comment: either save as csv or use PHPExcel

Comment: @Dagon any way to modify my code to work with PHPExcel?

Comment: open an excel file in notepad, what do you see ?

Comment: Can you redo your csv and do a var_dump in your while loop. At least if you display the output you are getting you will get better assistance. To read an Excel file is far more complicated than just passing it by a PHP function.

Comment: @Dagon It was alot of encoding word

Comment: His point is that if you cannot see text in notepad, php will not be able to read it either. .xls files are not an open format.

Comment: @ChrisRymer Is there sample code to convert my excel file into csv with php code and then insert the data into database?

Comment: I think you misunderstand, Excel cannot be natively parsed with php so you cannot use php to convert it to csv. You must either use Excel and do it manually or look for a library that will assist you. There is actualy one here but I have no idea how good it is [php excel parse](https://code.google.com/p/php-excel-reader/downloads/list)

Comment: How to use the php excel parse library ? @chris rymer

Comment: Sorry, you are on your own there, please make a csv and do a `print_r()` for any more help.

Comment: XLSX is a compressed file with XML files inside. You could extract and parse. Or just Save As... .csv

Answer (score 2):

You need to get the `index` of the *Column* and *row* using
 `$maxCol= getHightstColumn()` and get `$maxRow= HighestRow()` 
then
I would rather store the file in an array using rangeToArray in a for loop

```
for($row=1; $row<=maxRow;$row++) 
$rowData =$objSheet->rangeToArray('A' . $row . ':' . $maxCol . $row,  NULL,TRUE, FALSE)[0];
```

// from here you can work with index of the first row which you can start from row 2.

Best